# Simply insert data into a DB

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to php and have been trying to create a site using it. I have created a login page and am trying to provide the option to create a new user by inserting a username & pass into the DB. I feel like this is something simple that I'm missing but i'm not sure so hopefully someone can help :)

php ~

```
<?php
session_start();

unset($_SESSION["currentUser"]);
unset($_SESSION["currentUserID"]);

if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"]=="create") {

  $formUserC=$_POST["name"];
  $formPassC=$_POST["pword"];

  include("dbConnect.php");
  $dbQuery=$db->prepare("select * from users"); 
  $newAcc = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$formUserC', '$formPassC')";
  if($newAcc){
      echo "<p>Your account was successfully created.";
  }  
  else{
   echo "<p>Error</p>";
  }
 }

if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"]=="login") {

  $formUser=$_POST["username"];
  $formPass=$_POST["password"];

  include("dbConnect.php");
  $dbQuery=$db->prepare("select * from users where username=:formUser"); 
  $dbParams = array('formUser'=>$formUser);
  $dbQuery->execute($dbParams);
  $dbRow=$dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if ($dbRow["username"]==$formUser) {       
     if ($dbRow["password"]==$formPass) {
        $_SESSION["currentUser"]=$formUser;
        $_SESSION["currentUserID"]=$dbRow["id"];
        if (isset($_SESSION["homePage"])) 
             header("Location: addToBasket.php");
        else header("Location: homePage.html");    
     }
     else {
        header("Location: login.php?failCode=2");
     }
  } else {
        header("Location: login.php?failCode=1");
  }

 } else {

?>
```

html (mostly) ~

```
    <html >
    <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Flat HTML5/CSS3 Login Form</title>



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loginstyle.css">


</head>

<body>


  <div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form" name="create" method="post" action="login.php">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" name="pword" placeholder="pword"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create">
      <input type="submit" value="create"/>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form name="login" method="post" action="login.php">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
      <input type="submit" value="login"/>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
    <?php
   if (isset($_GET["failCode"])) {
      if ($_GET["failCode"]==1)
         echo "<h3 style='color:red;'>Invalid username entered</h3>";
      if ($_GET["failCode"]==2)
         echo "<h3 style='color:red;'>Invalid password entered</h3>";
   }     
?>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

   <script src="js/loginindex.js"></script>



</body>
</html>

<?php
    }
?>
```

P.S. some of it's code I nabbed from others. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$newacc` is just a string. You need to send it to the DB (as you did for the select). You also should parameterize that query (also as you did for the select) and hash the password.

Comment: far as I can tell, you never queried/executed the first two queries.

Comment: you also should add `exit;` to each header

Comment: Ahhh okay i'll see if i can try fix it here thanks :D

Comment: I tried $newAcc=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$formUserC', '$formPassC')";)
   $dbQuery->execute($newAcc); But it breaks it haha

Comment: That is not right. Look at your `select`, that is correct. `$dbQuery` has no relation here. The value for `execute` should be an array of your values and the variables need to be removed from your SQL. e.g. `$newAcc=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)")` `$newAcc->execute(array($formUserC, $formPassC));` but hash the password.

Comment: So my code now looks like,                                                
'$newAcc=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$formUserC', '$formPassC')")
   $dbParams = array($formUserC, $formPassC);
   $newAcc->execute($dbParams);'                                        Although it still seems to be broken, sorry about this my heads spinning i've been doing this all day haha

Comment: copied it exactly but still doesn't work :( Thank you for continuing to reply though

Comment: What happens? Error? Use the `@`  so notifications are sent.